#  can't display a  UILabel -xcode

Tags: objective-c, parsing, object, controller, label

i have a situation with a label!! i made a tableView which is connected with a data table on parse. when i select the row the view controller is pass on to the view but the values are! all my NSLog appoint to the fact that the data is passed! but i cannot display that on my viewController's label! please help.. what am i missing? all the connections are there with the files owner.. these are my files..

```
-(void) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSLog(@"%i",row);

MyTableViewDetail * MTD = [[MyTableViewDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewDetail" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"text=%@",[object objectForKey:@"columntext"]);
MTD.label1 = [object objectForKey:@"columntext"];
NSLog(@"label1= %@",MTD.label1);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:MTD animated:YES];
//tableView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];


}
```

all my NSLog's are pointing to the right direction. but for some reason the label1 is not displaying the value.. here are my other files..

```
#import "MyTableViewDetail.h"
#import "MyTableController.h"

@interface MyTableViewDetail ()

@end

@implementation MyTableViewDetail
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize imagedetail;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {


    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setLabel1:nil];
[self setImagedetail:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

and my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "MyTableController.h"

@interface MyTableViewDetail : UIViewController{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imagedetail;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the text of the label with `MTD.label1.text = ...` instead of `MTD.label1 = ...`.

**UPDATE:**

From the NSLog() output in your comments one can see that `MTD.label1` is `nil` initially.
The reason is that the label is connected only after the new view has actually been loaded. The solution is to create a separate property, e.g. "columntext" in `MyTableViewDetail`, and then

- set `MTD.columntext = [object objectForKey:@"columntext"];`,
- set `self.label1.text = self.columntext;` in `viewDidLoad` of `MyTableViewDetail`.

Comment: tried that also.. it doesn't work.. when i run MTD.label1=... the NSLog(@"label1= %@",MTD.label1); displays my desired result. when i run MTD.kabel1.text=... the NSLog displays "null". so i dont really know what am i missing at this point.

Comment: these are the NSLogs with MTD.label1.text=..

2012-08-26 15:15:08.790 pyxida3[7427:c07] 0
2012-08-26 15:15:08.790 pyxida3[7427:c07] text=test3
2012-08-26 15:15:08.790 pyxida3[7427:c07] label1= (null)

 and these this with MTD.label1=...
2012-08-26 15:16:57.457 pyxida3[7470:c07] 0
2012-08-26 15:16:57.457 pyxida3[7470:c07] text=test3
2012-08-26 15:16:57.457 pyxida3[7470:c07] label1= test3

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
 i ctrl and drag UILabel into my header file so its connected to the files owner.. i am stack at this point for 2 days and i honestly don't know what is wrong. would you mind to take a look with teamviewer?

Comment: @snksnk: I can try that, but I haven't use TeamViewer yet, I have to download and install first.